# Derefrencing an iterator to 2D vector and assigning its value to another 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, 2d-vector

I have a 2D vector  `vector<vector<int> > det;` and I want to assign the last value or the most recently `push_back`'d value to another 2D vector v.
 This is what I tried `v = *(det.rbegin());` but it shows an error. What is the correct way of doing it ?

 error message : conversion from 'std::vector' to non-scalar type 'std::vector >' requested

Comment: Consider reading the error message.

Comment: @ user2079303 I have read the error message already but what does  'std::vector >' mean ?

Comment: Provide the whole code please.

Comment: maybe you meant `v.push_back( *det.rbegin() );`

Comment: @M.M That is exactly what I wanted, I was just too careless writing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last entry of your 2D array is not a 2D array, i.e. of type vector < vector < int > >, but of type vector < int > .

As such it cannot be assigned to another variable of type

vector < vector < int > >

This works fine:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > det, det2;
    std::vector<int> vector1, vector2, vector3;

    vector1.push_back(3);
    vector1.push_back(4);
    vector1.push_back(5);

    vector2.push_back(13);
    vector2.push_back(14);
    vector2.push_back(15);

    vector3.push_back(113);
    vector3.push_back(114);
    vector3.push_back(115);

    std::vector<int> member_of_2darray;

    det.push_back(vector1);
    det.push_back(vector2);
    det.push_back(vector3);

    det2.push_back(det.back());

    std::cout<<det2[0][2]<<std::endl; // returns 115

    //last:element
    std::cout<<det.back().back()<<std::endl;


}
```

edit: if you deperately want to use iterators: here is an working example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > det, det2;
    std::vector<int> vector1, vector2, vector3;

    std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator it;

    vector1.push_back(3);
    vector1.push_back(4);
    vector1.push_back(5);

    vector2.push_back(13);
    vector2.push_back(14);
    vector2.push_back(15);

    vector3.push_back(113);
    vector3.push_back(114);
    vector3.push_back(115);

    std::vector<int> member_of_2darray;

    det.push_back(vector1);
    det.push_back(vector2);
    det.push_back(vector3);

    it = det.end();

    det2.push_back(*(it-1));

    std::cout<<det2[0][2]<<std::endl; //output: 115


}
```

Comment: I want to extract the value of the last element of det but the size of det is not known.

Comment: the last element of det.back(). Or, with an iterator it the last element is *(it - 1).

Comment: The problem was with the return type of *(det.rbegin()) which is vector<int> as you mentioned in your answer but the examples provided are in no way related to the answer.

Comment: I have a 2D vector vector<vector<int> > det; and I want to assign the last value or the most recently push_back'd value to another 2D vector v. This is what you asked for. I provided working examples that demonstrate how to do that. Anyway, if your problem is fixed, it does not matter.